# does the increase in subdomains help to load the multiple ajax finish faster?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a doubt regarding the multiple ajax calls.

Consider I have 100 ajax calls to make. If I used a single sub domain it is taking 30 sec to finish. But if I use 2 sub domains it is taking 20 secs & if I use 3 sub domains it is taking 18 secs.

All the Ajax calls are dynamic. The time to finish a call is a max of 3 sec.
Each call need to communicate with db. Previously I had a single db for all the 3 sub-domains. Now I created 3 different databases.

My concern is to get them finished in 10 secs.

Any suggestions please.

KR

Comment: PHP is not exactly the right choise when needing performance...

Comment: Instead of requesting server 100 times, use only one request sending all relevant data to server side script, handling all relevant logic...

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're describing is the limit of simultaneous connections that browser opens per single hostname. If you have many calls to one server, some of them will need to wait before the others are finished (which causes delays). If you distribute resources between servers you get around this per-server-limit and they run simultaneously. However for small amount of data it is usually wiser to just merge requests together and send as one package, as otherwise you loose time for each request to get back and forth + repeating useless headers, opening connection.

Check here for the current limits per browser. They might be nto strick implementing those limits, though.
http://www.browserscope.org/?category=network

Answer (score 0):

If the sub-domains are served by the same Apache server the performance will be a bit slower or almost the same because the Apache needs to serve more virtual hosts.

So the right choice would be to group your requests into one or use WebSocket to communicate with the server "real-time"

Comment: I got impression he gets poor performance on the client's side, which does not exactly need to mean poor server performance

Comment: Yeah, but the solution is the same: group the ajax calls or use WebSocket for "realtime" communication. 

I think the simultaneous connection limit is not set "just 4 fun", it is set to guide the developers to the right road. (do not create 100 requests per second)

Comment: well, yeap, just as I mentioned below ;)